# PHP / MYSQL SUM OF AUTHENTICATION LOGIN/LOGOUT TIMES

Tags: logging, authentication, logout

I have a simple authentication log formatted in mysql like this:

---

username | login_time | last_active

bob | 2012-01-01 22:00:00 | 2012-01-02 06:00:00

bob | 2012-01-02 08:00:00 | 2012-01-02 09:00:00

bob | 2012-01-02 23:00:00 | 2012-01-03 10:00:00

---

Now then, I'm trying to display a tally of the TOTAL hours the user worked in these timeframes:

0-24 hours ago

24-48 hours ago

48-72 hours ago

---

For the 24-48 example, I originally coded:

```
$start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-2 days"));
$end_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 days"));
$result_time = mysql_query("SELECT login_time,last_active FROM `auth_log` WHERE username = '".$row['username']."' AND login_time > '$start_time' AND login_time <= '$end_time' AND authenticated = 'yes'");
    while($row_time = mysql_fetch_array( $result_time )) {
        $time = strtotime($row_time['last_active']) - strtotime($row_time['login_time']);
        $tot_time = $tot_time + $time;
    }
$total_time = gmdate('H:i',$tot_time);
```

If our 24-48 hour time cutoffs are: 2012-01-02 00:00:00 and 2012-01-03 00:00:00 then, as shown in the database table above, row 1 and 3 will NOT be included in the query.  Only records that fall within the cutoff times will be shown (row 2). So this would show that Bob worked 1 hour when in fact, Bob worked 8 hours total within the 24-48 hour timeframe. (6 hours from row1 + 1 hr row2 + 1 hr row3)

So now I'm sort-of stuck.

I'm thinking there MUST be an easier way to do this.  Either my authentication database design sucks or else there is an easier way to get this info using mysql time/date queries or else I'm going to have to do really complex lookups like:

```
$start_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-2 days"));
$end_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 days"));
$result_time = mysql_query("
SELECT login_time,last_active FROM auth_log 
WHERE username = '$username' 
AND authenticated = 'yes'
AND (login_time >= '$start' AND last_active <= '$end') 
OR (login_time >= '$start' AND login_time <= '$end' AND last_active > '$end') 
OR (last_active >= '$start' AND last_active <= '$end' AND login_time < '$start') 
");
```

Any help sure would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$day_index = SELECT WEEKDAY(\''.$date.'\') AS day_index;

SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( t.diff ) ) AS suma
FROM (
    SELECT login_time, TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( logout_time, login_time ) ) AS diff
    FROM login_times
    WHERE user_id = '.$id.'
    AND DATE( login_time ) = SUBDATE(\''.$date.'\', '.$day_index.' )
) AS t
GROUP BY DATE( t.login_time )'
```

I have similar table like you and this query handles the selection properly, only instead of name I have `user_id`